# Проблема с динамическими angular ссылками на хостинге

Tags: javascript, angular

Сделала сайт на Angular https://pozitivtour74.ru/. На сайте может быть несколько поездок и при клике на кнопку "подробнее" переход по ссылке https://pozitivtour74.ru/:linkName, где будет подробная информация о поездках. Эти динамические ссылки сделала с помощью RouterModule, на локальной машине и при публикации на гид все работает.

Сейчас, если я перезагружаю страницу или сразу открываю https://pozitivtour74.ru/:linkName выходит ошибка "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server."

Что это значит? мне нужно каким-то образом покупать поддомен для сайта для каждой поездки?
Или может я как то неправильно задеплоила проект на хостинг?

Подскажите пожалуйста, первый раз выкладываю сайт на Хостинг.

Answer (score 2):

Нашла ответ здесь: https://angular-doc.ru/guide/deployment#fallback

Если коротко, то при адресе https://pozitivtour74.ru/:linkName сервер не отдает никакие файлы, это ошибочный поддомен и он выводит ошибку 404.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при ошибочном адресе возвращался исходный файл index.html, в котором уже скрипт angular с помощью RouterModule отрисует нужные компоненты для нужного адреса.

для этого нужно добавить в корневую папку файл .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: В телеграмме есть группа по ангуляру, там быстрее отвечают: https://t.me/angular_ru